# 2 installations of latex and lyx

Tags: lyx, installing, miktex2.9

(o.s windows 10 64 bit)
today I've installed lyx 2.3.1 from a hebrew website.
now the installation didnt find my current miktex installation (which is in program files folder) so it automatically installed new miktex installation in a new folder program files (x86)). ofcourse I dont want this multiple installations. what should I do? can I just pick one miktex installation and remove it using applications manager?
also I have previous version of lyx. 2.2 installed a year ago can I just remove  it using application manager?
thanks

Comment: Odd that it installed a 32bit version on your 64bit system could be due to non American user name  (spaces punctuation accents) ? you need to see if you can run the program files(x86) admin uninstall exe, I would also try to uninstall older lyx 2.2 with its own uninstaller as it hooks into the registry in many places. the best way to then move forward is install new single user MiKTeX 64bit (check you can run pdflatex ANYWHERE from command line) then install LyX 2.3 should see the 64bit MiKTeX

Comment: also both of my lyx folders are in program files (x86). folder

Comment: OK LyX installs in that folder for all users (as a 32bit application) so need to uninstall 2.2 as the same user that previously installed (admin OR basic) since LyX is 32bit it makes sense that it wants 32bit miktex